# Low quality image on print

Tags: c#, printing

I have a picturebox and I need to print it.

Application prints it, here is the code for print :

```
private void btnPrintSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tempstr = comboBox7.Text;
        if (!Directory.Exists(tempstr))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempstr);

            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
            doc.PrintPage += this.Doc_PrintPage;
            PrintDialog dlgSettings = new PrintDialog();
            dlgSettings.Document = doc;
            if (dlgSettings.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                doc.Print();
            }

            temp1 = comboBox1.Text;
            temp2 = comboBox2.Text;
            temp3 = comboBox3.Text;
            temp4 = comboBox4.Text;
            temp5 = comboBox5.Text;
            temp6 = comboBox6.Text;

            bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\"+ tempstr +"\\" + temp1 + temp2 + temp3 + temp4 + temp5 + temp6 + ".jpg");

    }

    private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)bmp, x, y);
    }
```

The only problem is that the picture is very blurry. Here is the final [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjWxd.png).

Does anyone knows how to fix this problem?

(P.S The final image must be 189(width) and 132(height))

Comment: _The final image must be 189(width) and 132(height)_ ??? 189 what?? pixels inches, mm??? And what size does the original image/picturebox have? Did you set the dpi to a fitting value for your printer? when targetting a printer using DrawToBitmap is usually not a good idea as screen controls and pritners have quite diiferent dpi values..! Better duplicate the code that draws on the picturebox with appropriate values for the larger printer surface!

Comment: Pixels, 633x381, and no i did not.How could i do that?

Comment: Please answer all questions: what do you mean by _The final image must be 189(width) and 132(height)_ ? Surely __not pixels__ as printer do not print pixels. They print real world units, like mm. BTW, there was a related qustion [here just now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116241/printing-a-panel-to-a-printer/34116606?noredirect=1#comment55982385_34116606)

Comment: Ok then, the picturebox must be printed in 5x3.5cm

Comment: The em size of the font is only 16 pixels.  That's but a fleck of dust on a 600 dots-per-inch printer, 0.026 inches aka 0.68 millimeters.  That's completely unreadable so the default scaling makes everything 6 times bigger.  Every single pixel in the image turns into a 6x6 blob of ink on paper.  Yeah, you notice that, those anti-aliasing pixels don't work.  Core problem here is that the resolution of your monitor is so much different from the printer.  That requires a very different way to generate the image.  Easy enough to do, you have to write the code instead of using DrawToBitmap().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the `dpi` you want your image to be printed in.

Your input and your desired output do **not** have the same *apect ratio*. If that is what you want, you need to calculate the necessary `dpi` values for width and height separately.

I code it in an extra explicit way to make it most understandable.

Also note that you always should use the `ClientSize` or `ClientRectangle` properties, so you are free to set any `BorderStyle`, as `Width` is the **outer** width..

```
    private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);

        float tgtWidthMM = 50;  // 5cm
        float tgtHeightMM = 35;  // 3.5cm
        float tgtWidthInches = tgtWidthMM / 25.4f;
        float tgtHeightInches = tgtHeightMM / 25.4f;
        float srcWidthPx = bmp.Width; //  633
        float srcHeightPx = bmp.Height; //  381
        float dpiX = srcWidthPx / tgtWidthInches;
        float dpiY = srcHeightPx / tgtHeightInches;

        bmp.SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY);

        pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)bmp, x, y);
    }
```

Also do add the `ImageFormat` parameter to the `Save` call:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
...

bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\"+ tempstr +"\\" + temp1 + temp2 +
         temp3 + temp4 + temp5 + temp6 + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

..or else the success of the save will depend on the source being created from a `jpg` as well..

But, of course, no matter what you do right, if there is not enough quality in the source, the result can't change that. And looking at your example I wonder just what the source of the image is?

- If you create the text with `Labels` and `TextBoxes` you really should write those texts instead via `DrawString` calls in the Print event, as only this will result in a high-quality output.
- If you are loading it into the `PictureBox` I wonder why you don't use the source image directly. Also: If you (ab)use the `PictureBox` as a zooming tool blurriness is to be expected. Do not do that! Instead zoom only in the `DrawImage` call using the overload with source- and target-rectangles! But again, the quality of the input limits the quality of the output!

Comment: TaW, thanks for your answer and explanation...it worked :-)